# AWS Cognito - Access and refresh token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

I am currently switching from IBM APIC to AWS API Gateway. I found a different behaviour that it's not detailed in the AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html)

After i use the `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token` i have a different behavior:

- In IBM the initial `access_token` is invalidated.
- In AWS you can call the API with the initial `access_token` and with the "new" `access_token`.

Is there an option to invalidate the initial `access_token` when the `refresh_token` is used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So I think what you're seeing here is that old token is still valid, in short no you can't invalidate it UNLESS you call global sign out. I think the minimum time a token takes to expire 60 minutes.

Cognito has some flaws still really, listUsers API doesn't search by custom attributes, if you use federated identities you can't retrospectively link by email as you've found the token implementation isn't quite ideal yet.

Comment: I think you cannot change the time in which the `access_token` expires. Only the time for `refresh_token`.

Comment: Yeah acccess_token is fixed, you're only other option is to issue your own JWT's and use a custom authoriser.